# How can I disable anonymous login to controllers using Kestrel?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

HttpSys has `Authentication.AllowAnonymous`, but Kestrel does not have a similar setting.

How can I massively deny anonymous access to controllers without using attributes? To ask for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
public class DenyAnonymousMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DenyAnonymousMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User?.Identity?.Name) && !endpoint.Metadata.OfType<AllowNullAttribute>().Any())
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            var values = new StringValues(new string[] { "Negotiate", "NTLM" });
            context.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate, values);
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized Windows User");
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```